# Ionic: image in column expands grid layout

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, grid, cross-platform

I have a a ion-grid filled with images in each column. 
My Plan is to have two images per row.

**Problem:** If I have only one image per row, the image expands to the full row size which is not what I want. 
How can I achieve, that a column does not expand if there are not enough columns to fill the row.

**Question:** Shouldn't `width-50` prevent image expanding even if there is only one per row?

Screenshots of my problem where the image expands if there is only one per row:

[image]

**layout code**:

```
  <ion-grid >
        <ion-row *ngFor="let row of grid; let i = index">
          <ion-col width-50 *ngFor="let col of row; let j = index">
            <img src="{{col}}" (click)="showImage(i, j)">
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

So what I want to achieve is that all images are always inline - no matter if a row contains one or two images.

**Note**: I have noticed, that the table is working properly on large spaces like the browser.

Comment: have you tried to put a class on the picture and add an overflow: hidden ?

Comment: just use `col-6` instead of `width-50`. See about [Ionic grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/)